# #MongoSocketException #JaversBuildException

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, javers

Getting the below error while building the project on Jenkins,
Same is getting build on local environment.

## MongoSocketException

## JaversFromStarter Bean not getting created

[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 41.849 s <<< FAILURE! - in in.evergreenrevolution.egr.EgrApplicationTests
[ERROR] contextLoads(in.evergreenrevolution.egr.EgrApplicationTests) Time elapsed: 0.001 s <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'JaversFromStarter' defined in class path resource [org/javers/spring/boot/mongo/JaversMongoAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.javers.core.Javers]: Factory method 'javers' threw exception; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)}}]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.javers.core.Javers]: Factory method 'javers' threw exception; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)}}]
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)}}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install Mongo DB Server on your local machine or VM

[MongoDB Installation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/install-community/)

Comment: Thanks...!! that worked,, i didn't installed mongo server on my VM.

Answer (score 0):

Your build environment is point to localhost, most likely you do not (and do not want to have) MongoDB installed on the build server. Just change you config and point to your mongod.